# my javascript function does not load on initial page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, angular

I'm building an app with an Angular2 frontend and a web API backend using the asp.net Angular2 template. I have an inline script in my index.html file that does not get loaded on the initial page load, but when i refresh the page it gets loaded. Below is the code.

```
<script>

            $(function () {
                $('.toggle-nav').click(
                    function () {
                        $('#body-holder').toggleClass('show-nav');
                        return false;
                    });
            });

</script>
```

I tried loading it in my component.ts file within the ngOnInit function but i get a cannot find $ error when i try that.

Comment: Can provide the full error message ?

Comment: Add script before the end of body tag, and wrap everything inside a `$(document).ready(function(){})`

Comment: @azs06 `$(function(){})` is exact same thing as `$(document).ready(function(){})`

Comment: @charlietfl yes you are right.Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: How have you referenced the jQuery library?

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var $:any; // this is required
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `Something`
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
        $('.toggle-nav').click(function () {
                $('#body-holder').toggleClass('show-nav');
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: also `return false;` is not required